# msi not getting unistalled properly

Tags: installshield, installscript

I want to revert all my custom action on uninstallation.

Here are my custom action

1. Create a registry entry using installscript
2. Install service  --> created under launch an executable option
3. Start Service    --> created under launch an executable option

Here is code that I wrote in installscript to add a registry entry

```
#include "ifx.h"

export prototype SetRegistryParameters(HWND);


function SetRegistryParameters(hMSI)
    NUMBER  ret;
    STRING  formatStr;
begin

    RegDBSetDefaultRoot(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE);
    SprintfBox(WARNING, "SetRegistryParameters", "Hi from internal", 0);

    ret = RegDBSetKeyValueEx("Software\\XYZ", "InstallDir", REGDB_STRING, INSTALLDIR, -1);
    if (ret < 0) then
        formatStr = "RegSetValue failed with ret: 0x%x";
        SprintfBox(WARNING, "SetRegistryParameters", formatStr, ret);
    endif;

    return ret;

end;
```

To stop the service and remove it  I created custom actions

1. StopService      --> created under launch an executable option
2. RemoveService    --> created under launch an executable option

To remove a registry entry I wrote a installscript code,

```
export prototype DeleteRegistryParameters(HWND);

function DeleteRegistryParameters(hMSI)
    // To Do:  Declare local variables. 
begin

    // To Do:  Write script that will be executed when MyFunction is called.

    RegDBSetDefaultRoot(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE);
    SprintfBox(WARNING, "SetRegistryParameters", "Bye from internal", 0);

    ret = RegDBDeleteKey("XYZ");
    if (ret < 0) then
        formatStr = "RegSetValue failed with ret: 0x%x";
        SprintfBox(WARNING, "SetRegistryParameters", formatStr, ret);
    endif;  
    return ret;
end;
```

Here is sequence of all actions

```
1. Create a registry entry using installscript 
    Install Execute Sequence = After CostFinalize
    Install Execute Condition: "Not INSTALLED"
2. Install Service
    Install Execute Sequence = After SetRegistryParameters
    Install Execute Condition: "Not INSTALLED"
3. Start Service 
    Install Execute Sequence = After Install Service
    Install Execute Condition: "NOT Installed"
4. Stop Service 
    Install Execute Sequence = After InstallFiles
    Install Execute Condition: Remove = "ALL"
5. Remove Service
    Install Execute Sequence = After Stop Service
    Install Execute Condition: Remove = "ALL"
6. Remove Registry
    Install Execute Sequence = After Remove Service
    Install Execute Condition: Remove = "ALL"
```

But the package is not getting uninstalled and

Comment: From the little shown here, I would suggest using the built-in Windows Installer support for services and registry keys. (BTW, your question appears to end abruptly mid-thought.)

Comment: @MichaelUrman Sorry about that..But I am building package using installshield..

Comment: I don't understand the contradiction there. InstallShield exposes the built-in support in the Services view (found only under components in earlier versions, but also as its own view more recently) and the Registry view (available under components or as its own view).

Comment: @MichaelUrman I am creating a service using python. Hope it help you understand problem

Comment: Michael is right as usual.  There is no contradiction... ditch the custom actions and use the built in features of the Windows Installer framework that InstallShield natively authors.

Answer (score 1):

A service is a service is a service.  Doesn't matter if it's C++, C#, Java, .PL, .PY using ServAny.exe or whatever.  Windows Installer's ServiceInstall and ServiceControl tables can handle it.  The Registry table handles Registry.  InstallShield authores MSI's.  In other words, ditch the custom actions and get rollback / uninstall for free.

See: [Zataoca: Custom actions are (generally) an admission of failure.](http://robmensching.com/blog/posts/2007/8/17/zataoca-custom-actions-are-generally-an-admission-of-failure/)

> a.  The setup developer wrote a custom action that was already
>   supported by the underlying engine. This is essentially reinventing
>   the wheel with a less stable solution.  Invariably this comes down to
>   lack of documentation or lack of effort on the developer's part. 
>   Either way a failure to use the most optimal solution.

Comment: I was exactly waiting for you master..Thanks for ans..But real mess is I have to fire some command to install, start, stop , remove service (like `python service.py --startup auto install`)

Comment: And I also want the service to get installed and started only when I set some registry values.

Comment: No, you don't. Run that command once on a VM and observe what it authors into the registry under HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services.   Use that information as the requiresments for the ServiceInstall table.  The service metadata is the requirement, the python command is just one possible implementation of that and isn't compatible with the MSI model.

Comment: Associate the registry data and service data to a component or feature and use the feature tree or conditional expressions to control whether that component gets installed or not.  This way the two actions always occur together atomically.

Comment: Master I am completely newbie to this installshield. Please bear me.. I will surely try whatever you said.But please hlp me if I get stuck somewhere. I do not understood your  ***No, you don't. Run that command once on a VM and...*** comment..+1 for suggestion

Comment: Email me, we can do a screen sharing session.  The point of running the command on a VM is to profile/reverse engineer the registry changes made by the command.  Once you look at this registry key you'll realize it's all the properties in the services view of InstallShield. You then no longer need to run the command in your installer.  MSI will do the work for you and what MSI does it knows how to rollback and uninstall automatically.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51470/discussion-between-pilot-and-christopher-painter)